# Vbs script is not being started during installation

Tags: vbscript, wix, wix3.6

I`m currently new to Wix and having trouble with a vbs script that should be run at the end of the installation process.

What do I have so far:

I was able to insert several files and registry calls into my msi file. The installation process works fine, all files are stored in a proper folder and the registry is being updated.
Now, I`m trying to call a vbs script at the end of the installation process. The script itself is nothing special, for starters it should just display a message box.

I created a custom action prior to this document (Custom Action Type 6):
http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/21/from-msi-to-wix-part-5-custom-actions.aspx

The following is being displayed when running the msi file:

'There is a problem with this Windows Installer package.
A script required for this install to complete could not be 
run. Contact your support personnnel or package vendor.'

I tried to implement and run the script in wix like this:

```
<Binary Id="dasd" SourceFile="C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\administrator\Desktop\dasd.vbs" />
<CustomAction Id="DoSomething" BinaryKey="dasd" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" VBScriptCall="" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="DoSomething" Before="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The attribute 'VBScriptCall' previously had the value 'Main'. I deleted it, because I am not using a function called 'Main'. I thought that 'Main' wold just run the complete script. However, it`s neither working with 'Main' nor without it.

I`m under the impression that it is not required to have the script file on the file system (during execution of the msi file). May I be wrong here?

Might anyone figure out what`s going wrong here?

Best regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I was able to solve the problem.
The path to the vbs script was wrong:

```
<Binary Id="dasd" SourceFile="C:\Dokumente und codeEinstellungen\administrator\Desktop\dasd.vbs" />
```

I edited the path in the wxs file manually to 'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen[...]\dasd.vbs' by mistake. WixEdit just sets it to 'dasd.vbs', which is correct in this case.

Maybe someone may find this helpful and doesn`t have to search for too long to solve the case ;-).

Best regards,
Markus

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong:
"I`m under the impression that it is not required to have the script file on the file system (during execution of the msi file). May I be wrong here?"

The file needs to be present in the file system. copy it to the particular location using the you WIX script and then everything should be fine.

Comment: Well, I`m not sure how to save the script file and reference it in Wix to be run.
I did the following:

`code`<Component Id="dasd.vbs" DiskId="1" Guid="">`code`
<File Id="dasd.vbs" Name="dasd.vbs" Source="C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\administrator\Desktop\dasd.vbs" />
</Component>[/code]

This 'packs' the file into the msi.

`code`<ComponentRef Id="dasd.vbs" />

This references the file and copies to a user-defined directory.

`code`<Binary Id="dasd" SourceFile="C:\Dokumente und `code`Einstellungen\administrator\Desktop\dasd.vbs" />

Do I still need this? What about the path reference?

Comment: Sorry for wrong use of the code tag. It`s really obvious that I`m new to stackoverflow ;-).